# Applescript running fine when started from script editor, but working when run as a service

Tags: macos, automation, applescript, ui-automation, automator

I am currently working on an Applescript to automate hosting a meeting. The script works perfectly fine when run from within Apple's script editor or even when started from within Automator. But as soon as i save the service and bind it to a keyboard-shortcut, it stops working. It runs and the first few steps work fine, but as soon as it gets to pressing buttons it doesn't work anymore. The part of the script it get stuck on when started from the keyboard shortcut looks like this:

```
                tell process "GoToMeeting"
                click menu item "Unmute Me" of menu "Audio" of menu bar 1
                delay 1
                click menu item "Share My Webcam" of menu "Webcams" of menu bar 1
                delay 3
                tell application "System Events" to tell process "GoToMeeting"
                    set value of attribute "AXFullScreen" of window 1 to true
```

Comment: At a guess, `set value of attribute "AXFullScreen" of window 1 to true` is likely problematic.  Well, any script that depends on `clicks` and `delays` is problematic by its very nature.  But I suspect that when you make a window fullscreen, one of two things happens: either the application process loses focus, so no longer accepts control by _System Events_; or the app keeps focus, but it goes to the fullscreen window, which now occupies a different desktop/space, in which the rest of the UI elements do not exist, and are only accessible again once switching back to the main desktop.

Comment: @CJK once an app goes full screen, the menu bar becomes inaccessible, both to normal usage and GUI scripting. You have to force the menu bar to appear first (which can be done by programmatically moving the mouse to the top of the screen) before you can click on menu items.  I expect that other aspects of the GUI hierarchy change as well, so that the drill-down to specific elements might be different. You can test for this with an external monitor: put the app in full screen on one monitor, and use the Script Editor (or some other tool) on the other monitor to explore the GUI.

Comment: @TedWrigley Isn’t that pretty much exactly what I said ?

Comment: @CJK — More or less.  I was merely adding details and diagnostics. No worries.

Comment: @TedWrigley Oh, of course. It’s good to have someone else follow on to provide additional insight, or even just word something in a better way. Sorry if I made you think your comment was unwelcome (on the contrary, it’s great and the investigative tip is especially useful). I was only confused: I thought it addressed me to make a correction (which would be totally fine, btw), and I figured you spotted the bit I wondered if anyone would pick up wasn’t quite true, and when that wasn’t it, I should have been like _Where In The World Is Carmen Sandiego?_ but I was so _Where’s Waldo?_